# Group by key in array that is inside a document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

i new in MongoDB and i have a documment in mongo with this structure:

```
{    
"game" : "chess",
"name" : "Chess",
"prizes" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("562575c61d41c81efce7bc1b"),
        "group" : 0,
        "name" : "10 coins",
        "pos" : "0",
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("562575c61d41c81efce7bc1c"),
        "group" : 0,
        "name" : "10 coins",
        "pos" : "1",
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("562575c61d41c81efce7bc1d"),
        "group" : 1,
        "name" : "20 coins",
        "pos" : "2",
    }, 
}
```

I need to get some like this:

```
{    
"game" : "chess",
"name" : "Chess",
"prizes" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "10 coins",
        "group" : 0,
    },
    {
        "name" : "20 coins",
        "group" : 1,
    }
```

I try with aggregate and projection and unwind but i don't get the structure that i need, thanks.

Comment: Post the aggregation you have tried in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like below. Use $map with some set operation $setUnion or $setDifference, only needed to filter duplicates  while transforming the shape.

```
aggregate([{
    "$project": {
        "game": 1,
        "name": 1,
        "prizes": {
            "$setUnion": [{
                    "$map": {
                        "input": "$prizes",
                        "as": "prize",
                        in: {
                            "name": "$$prize.name",
                            "group": "$$prize.group"
                        }
                    }
                },
                []
            ]
        }
    }
}]).pretty();
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically I'm unwinding and then getting the prizes array down to just the fields you want based on your questions desired output. then group them all together using the game and name and using $addToSet to insert unique entires of group and name into the array. Im making the assumption of no duplicate games but I think it would work anyway since they would just all get grouped in together.

```
db.docs.aggregate([
   {$unwind : '$prizes'},
   {$project: {name: '$name', game: '$game', prizes: {group: '$prizes.group', name: '$prizes.name'}}},
   {$group: {_id: {name: '$name', game: '$game'}, prizes: {$addToSet: '$prizes'}}},
])
```